# Angularjs pagination only display 1

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I cant paginate the data that return from my **$http** it only display only 1 page. I follow this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview) but still dont know the problem why it dont paginate.

This is my script

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 2;
$scope.maxSize = 5;

$scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = response.data; //return of $http
}
$scope.makeTodos();

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
    var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.names = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
    console.log($scope.todos.slice(begin, end));
});
```

This is the inside of **response.data**

```
{"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
{"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
{"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
{"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
{"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
{"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
{"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
{"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
{"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
{"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}
```

**EDITED**

This is my HTML

```
<body ng-controller="TodoController">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <h4>{{todos.length}} total</h4>
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
      <li>{{x.id}}</li>
      <li>{{x.name}}</li>
      <li>{{x.description}}</li>
      <li>{{x.field3}}</li>
      <li>{{x.field4}}</li>
      <li>{{x.field5}}</li>
    </ul>
    <pagination 
      ng-model="currentPage"
      total-items="names.length"
      max-size="maxSize"  
      boundary-links="true">
    </pagination>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you show your code in html page

Comment: Have you added `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency? Have you included `ui-bootstrap` in your html code?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary yes I added ui-bootstrap

Comment: Html code please.

Comment: @ThanhTùng done added html

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary done added html

Comment: Have you added `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency in your module.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary yes I added already as I see in plunker Id already added the `ui.bootstrap` in that order also only 1 display in my pagination in my code it was 2 per page so in pagination it should be 5 but it only display 1

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization your ng-repeat is wrong

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary This is my module `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: @ThanhTùng I already did that still the pagination is only displaying 1

Comment: make sure your response.data is in proper array structure, in your provided response i cannot see square brackets
plus please share output of `console.log($scope.todos.slice(begin, end));`

Comment: @muneebShabbir It have a square bracket and the console.log display like this `{"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
{"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pagination component just add `items-per-page='numPerPage'` attribute then your paging will work accordingly

Your final code will be like

```
<pagination 
      ng-model="currentPage"
      total-items="names.length"
      items-per-page='numPerPage'
      max-size="maxSize"  
      boundary-links="true">
</pagination>
```

Here is updated example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BL8LB34hXSg2WVVCLqRD?p=preview)